# C# difference Task vs Backgroundworker

Tags: c#, task, backgroundworker

i try to understand the difference between Tasks and Backgroundworker respectively the using of it.

question 1: what is the difference? it is better management of system-resources? excepting the different syntax.

question2:
in a backgroundWorker i can wait inside for a event or its end before jump back (**While (bw.isbusy && !bw.CancellationPending)**). How to do this in a Task?

question 3:
BW.supportscancelation = true. How to do this in a Task?

I lack the perspective here ;-(

Thanks for your support!

Chris

Comment: Let `BackgroundWorker` (which is now an *obsolete* class) rest in peace, use `Task`s; `await Task.Delay(milliseconds);` to wait `milliseconds`; `await OtherTask;` - wait for some other task. Use `CancellationTokekSource` and `CancellaionToken` to cancel task execution

Comment: Thanks Dmitry!

But how i can get; set; CancelationToken. do you have a simple example?

Comment: As a simple demo, let's cancel task (`SomeTask`) if it executes more than `2` seconds: `using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(2000)) {
        try {
          await SomeTask(cts.Token);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException) {
          /*SomeTask cancelled*/
        }`
      }

Comment: oh! thats all? 

Thanks!